# Most simple react code not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am a newbie and missing something. I get no errors when I do npm start and when I open in the browser only the page title is displayed the react does not render the hello world message. What is going wrong???? I have spent too much time on this. No errors in the dev tools, the react developer tools does not detect the page as a react page. I dont know why?

My HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>What's the weather dear?</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="checkabc"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.jsx is

```
  import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    ReactDOM.render(
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
      document.getElementById('checkabc')
    );
```

webpack.config.js

```
    const webpack = require('webpack');
    const TransferWebpackPlugin = require('transfer-webpack-plugin');
    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
    module.exports = {
      entry: './src/index.jsx',
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
      },
      devtool: 'eval',
      output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        publicPath: '/',
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [{
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: { presets: ['react', 'es2016'] },
            }],
          },
        ],
      },
      plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: 'src/public/index.html' }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new TransferWebpackPlugin([
          { from: 'src/public' },
        ], '.'),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env': {
            ENDPOINT: JSON.stringify(process.env.ENDPOINT || 'http://0.0.0.0:9000/api'),
          },
        }),
      ],
    };
```

EDIT: Now I have index.js in the output in webpack.config.js and added  in the html. But Now I get the following error in console:

```
webpack:///./~/fbjs/lib/invariant.js?:51 Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
    at invariant (webpack:///./~/fbjs/lib/invariant.js?:44:15)
    at Object._renderNewRootComponent (webpack:///./~/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js?:310:126)
    at Object._renderSubtreeIntoContainer (webpack:///./~/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js?:401:32)
    at Object.render (webpack:///./~/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js?:422:23)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/index.jsx?:10:51)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/index.js:1513:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/index.js:660:30)
    at fn (http://localhost:8080/index.js:86:20)
    at eval (webpack:///multi_(webpack)-dev-server/client?:2:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/index.js:2569:1)
```

npm start gives following output:

```
@DESKTOP-UEH2PDD ~/projects/weatherapp/frontend
$ npm start

> weatherapp-frontend@0.0.1 start C:\cygwin64\home\dverma\projects\weatherapp\frontend
> webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js --progress --inline --colors

 10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active
Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
webpack output is served from /
Hash: 8cf92ee37f2a5067b1c4
Version: webpack 2.7.0
Time: 1859ms
       Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
 \img\09.svg    1.39 kB          [emitted]
    index.js    1.19 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
\favicon.ico    15.1 kB          [emitted]
 \index.html  353 bytes          [emitted]
  \style.css  190 bytes          [emitted]
 \img\01.svg    1.32 kB          [emitted]
 \img\02.svg    1.79 kB          [emitted]
  index.html  409 bytes          [emitted]
 \img\03.svg  801 bytes          [emitted]
 \img\04.svg  801 bytes          [emitted]
 \img\11.svg    1.82 kB          [emitted]
 \img\10.svg    1.39 kB          [emitted]
 \img\13.svg    1.74 kB          [emitted]
 \img\50.svg  471 bytes          [emitted]
chunk    {0} index.js (main) 1.03 MB [entry] [rendered]
  [115] ./src/index.jsx 176 bytes {0} [built]
  [116] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 5.83 kB {0} [built]
  [136] ./~/html-entities/index.js 231 bytes {0} [built]
  [139] ./~/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js 6.74 kB {0} [built]
  [143] ./~/punycode/punycode.js 14.7 kB {0} [built]
  [147] ./~/react-dom/index.js 59 bytes {0} [built]
  [231] ./~/react/react.js 56 bytes {0} [built]
  [259] ./~/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0} [built]
  [261] ./~/url/url.js 23.3 kB {0} [built]
  [262] ./~/url/util.js 314 bytes {0} [built]
  [263] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.6 kB {0} [built]
  [264] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 856 bytes {0} [built]
  [266] (webpack)/hot nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 160 bytes {0} [built]
  [267] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 77 bytes {0} [built]
  [268] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.jsx 40 bytes {0} [built]
     + 254 hidden modules
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
    chunk    {0} index.html 541 kB [entry] [rendered]
        [0] ./~/lodash/lodash.js 540 kB {0} [built]
        [1] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/public/index.html 725 bytes {0} [built]
        [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
        [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser's devTools?

Comment: No errors in the dev tools, the react developer tools does not detect the page as a react page. I dont know why?

Comment: You have not included bundle.js file in your index.html file

Comment: Where are you including the react component in your index.html?

Comment: Isnt <div id="checkabc"></div> enough? and how do i create bundle.js?

Comment: @win you need to `npm build` to create the bundle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all replace the output filename extension in webpack config from .jsx to .js and then after you run webpack , a bundled file is generated by webpack at `/` with the name `index.js` and you need to include this file in `index.html`

webpack.config.js

```
output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>What's the weather dear?</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="checkabc"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> NOTE: Replace the `./path/to/index.js` with your path relative to the
>   `index.html`

Comment: Try to include index.js at the end of the body, see the updated code

Comment: Thanks Shubham ! yes it fixed the issues :-)

Comment: Happy to help :)